# Phone stuck at 0% battery

Tags: battery, charging, motorola-moto-g, lineageos

I have a Moto G phone. I'm using LineageOS. Yesterday I notice my phone went dead. When I press power button, a white light in the camara flashes three times, which I understand to be no battery. It did have enough battery though.

When I connect the phone to charge (using PC), the 0% battery charging screen shows up. But it's stuck there at 0%. I can get to the boot menu (power button and volume down), which shows me "battery low", but when trying to boot recovery or any option, the phone restarts but is again stuck at low battery.

My guess is that the battery is gone. Since it cannot be charged, the OS doesn't have the power to load anything. However, it should load when the phone is connected and "charging". Perhaps the problem is not the battery itself but the phone recognising that the battery **does have enough charge**. Is this possible? Anyway, any idea is more than welcome.

Comment: first, PC can not really charge (<500mA) use the original charger. second, don't boot just leave it off while charging. third, powering phone with charger only does not work without battery, because charger doesn't give stable dc current

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION:** I have same problem on Moto G6 running Android 9. My phone was on charger all night but showed 0% in the morning. However, it appeared to have some charge as I was able to make and receive phone calls and texts. The battery status icon was just stuck on 0%.

**Here is the FIX that worked for me.**

1. If your phone is working but shows 0% battery all the time, proceed to #2.
2. Hold down the (Vol-) + (Power) buttons until you see the bootloader screen.
   (Note: do **NOT** release buttons until you see the bootloader menu screen. Also, do not worry if the camera takes a screenshot. Just keep holding the (Vol-) + (Power) buttons until the bootloader screen appears).
3. Use (Vol-) or (Vol+) button to change menu option to **[Qcom]**.
   [pressing (Vol-) or (Vol+) scroll through options].
   I pressed (Vol-) 7 times or (Vol+) 3 times to reach **[Qcom]**.
   Your phone may be different. Just stop when you see the **[Qcom]** option.
4. Press (Power) button to choose the **[Qcom]** option.
5. The phone should reboot automatically and the battery icon will display the correct %.

I hope this method works for you. it worked for me. GOOD LUCK :)

Comment: i can't see the option i scrolled through the options and it didn't show up.

Comment: It's possible your phone doesn't have a qCom processor.? Don't worry.. you can try the following.
Assuming you have your phone on charger over night or a long time..  and the 0% is showing in screen.  Try just pressing and holding the Power Button" for a long time.. maybe a couple minutes.. maybe 4 or  5 minutes. Your phone should come alive then release the "Power Button".  This has worked for me. Just be patient and be sure the phone has been plugged in for awhile.  Good Luck  :)